Force data initialization on custom module installation
I have a module that needs to initialize its database tables with data acquired from the existing site. What hook should I use?
hook_install() is obviously not suited for longer operations and doesn't have the support of the batch API, either.
hook_update_N() would be suitable (within the usual limitations) but it is not invoked when a module is installed, but only when a module is updated.
hook_post_update_NAME() would be promising (also in that it allows us to use the full Drupal without restrictions) but it's also contingent on a database update running first. If there's no update (again, direct installation of the latest version), it won't be called.

Starting from Drupal 7, Drupal core uses a new hook for reacting to every module installation: hook_modules_installed().
Differently from hook_install(), this hook can be implemented by all the modules, not just the module that has been right installed.
Its first parameter is an array containing the list of installed modules; its second parameter is TRUE if the module is being installed as part of a configuration import.
As for using the batch API from hook_modules_installed(), locale_modules_installed(), an implementation of that hook done by a Drupal core module, calls locale_system_update(), which contains the following code.
$options = _locale_translation_default_update_options();
$batch = locale_translation_batch_update_build($list, [], $options);
batch_set($batch);

Since a Drupal core module uses that code, I would say it is safe to use the batch API within hook_modules_installed().
function mymodule__modules_installed($modules) {
  // Verify mymodule is one of the installed modules,
  // or this hook will execute the same code all the times
  // a module is installed.
  if (in_array('mymodule', $modules)) {
    // Add your code.
  }
}


Thank you, very nice idea, I never met that hook before. :-) In hindsight, yes, the translation update after every installation, I could have guessed there was something like that.

I remember when that hook has been introduced in Drupal 7. I probably wrote an implementation for it at least twice, but then I forgot about it.
